Cannot use "scale" when plotting with Polars (Python) and Altair?
Consider the following minimal not-working example (it is a Jupyter Notebook): https://github.com/bzm3r/polars-plotting-issue/blob/86e8d926e1ac29feb0cac299e72f85c8e3192f9a/src/polars_plotting_issue/color_scheme.ipynb
There are two ways in which we can plot a Polars dataframe: either through the API provided by Polars, or using altair directly.
It seems that if we are using the API provided by Polars, we run into an error that does not occur if we use altair directly:
SchemaValidationError: `Tooltip` has no parameter named 'scale'

Existing parameter names are:
shorthand      bin         format       title   
aggregate      condition   formatType   type    
bandPosition   field       timeUnit             

See the help for `Tooltip` to read the full description of these parameters

Why is that? Should this be posted as an issue on the Polars repo?

There is a recent altair issue posted https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/18830 - it seems someone has mentioned the scale issue in there also. May be worth adding a reply in there or creating a new issue.

there's an open pull request to address it, maybe in the next Polars release it'll be ok

As mentioned in the comments, this is being solved. A temp fix is adding as a parameter tooltip=['index']

what does tooltip=['index'] do?

It makes the 'index' interactive, it will display the value when hovering above a point with your cursor
